# Render column based on another column's value

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, renderer

I'm making a custom grid that shows the ID and the status of specific orders. It is currently like this:

[image: grid]

I wanna make column Order ID background color change, depending on Status column value. How can I make that?

This are both my renderers:

ID:

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
    $value =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
    if ($value || !empty($value)) {
        return '<span style="font-size: 15px">'.$value.'</span>';
    }
}
```

and Status:

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
    $value =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
    if ($value || !empty($value)) {
        if ($value == '1') {
            return '<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 15px">' . $value . '</span></div>';
        } elseif ($value == '2') {
            return '<div style="background: limegreen; width: 100%; padding: 1px; border-radius: 15px; text-align: center;"><span style="color: white; font-size: 15px">' . $value . '</span></div>';
        } elseif ($value == '3') {
            return '<div style="background: green; width: 100%; padding: 1px; border-radius: 15px; text-align: center;"><span style="color: white; font-size: 15px">' . $value . '</span></div>';
        } elseif ($value == '4') {
            return '<div style="background: red; width: 100%; padding: 1px; border-radius: 15px; text-align: center;"><span style="color: white; font-size: 15px">' . $value . '</span></div>';
        }
    } else {
        return '<div style="width: 100%; padding: 1px; border-radius: 15px; text-align: center;"><span style="color: white; font-size: 15px">Sem Informações</div></span>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're not sure how to access the `status` property within the column renderer for the `id` property. Is that right?

If so, then you need only to understand what `$row` is: it is the [order] model you are working with on the current row. Therefore, even within your renderer for the `id` column, you can easily call `$row->getStatus()` in a conditional branch as you do with the `status` column renderer.

It might look like this (using your own code as sample):

```
public function renderIdColumn(Varien_Object $row)
{
    $status = $row->getStatus();
    $id = $row->getId();

    if ($status || !empty($status)) {
        if ($status == '1') {
            return '<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 15px">' . $id . '</span></div>';
        } elseif ($status == '2') {
            return '<div style="background: limegreen; width: 100%; padding: 1px; border-radius: 15px; text-align: center;"><span style="color: white; font-size: 15px">' . $id . '</span></div>';
        } elseif ($status == '3') {
            return '<div style="background: green; width: 100%; padding: 1px; border-radius: 15px; text-align: center;"><span style="color: white; font-size: 15px">' . $id . '</span></div>';
        } elseif ($status == '4') {
            return '<div style="background: red; width: 100%; padding: 1px; border-radius: 15px; text-align: center;"><span style="color: white; font-size: 15px">' . $id . '</span></div>';
        }
    } else {
        return '<div style="width: 100%; padding: 1px; border-radius: 15px; text-align: center;"><span style="color: white; font-size: 15px">Sem Informações</div></span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: oooooh, thank you. Yes, I was quite confused about $row. It worked fine, thanks